# Running task in the background?

Tags: google-compute-engine

If we are submitting a task to the compute engine through ssh from host machine and if we shut down the host machine is there a way that we can get hold of the output of the submitted task later on when we switch on the host machine?

Comment: Did you have the chance to test my answer? Did it worked?

Answer (score 0):

From the Linux point of view ‘ssh’ and ‘gcloud compute ssh’ are commands like all the others, therefore it is possible to redirect their output to a file while the command is performed using for example `>>` to redirect and append stdout to a file or `2>>` to store stderr.

For example if you run from the first instance 'name1':

```
$ gcloud compute ssh name2 --command='watch hostname' --zone=XXXX >> output.out
```

where 'name2' is the second instance, and at some point you shutdown 'name1' you will find stored into output.out the output provided by the command till the shutdown occurred.

Note that there is also the possibility to create shut down scripts, that in this scenario could be useful in order to upload output.out to a bucket or to perform any kind of clean-up operation.
In order to do so you can run the following command

```
$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata example-instance --metadata-from-file shutdown-script=path/to/script_file
```

Where the content of the script could be something like

```
#! /bin/bash
gsutil cp path/output.out gs://yourbucketname
```

Always keep in mind that Compute Engine only executes shutdown scripts on a best-effort basis and does not guarantee that the shutdown script will be run in all cases.

[More Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances) about shutdown scrips if needed.